# webapp hangs around in memory, WebDev.WebServer40.EXE not being torn down

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am running/debugging an asp.net mvc3 application from within Visual Studio 2010.

Anything static in nature is not called when I re-run the app from within Visual Studio.

(or even something simple like `Application_Start()`)

Each time I want to run the webapp 'properly' I need to kill `WebDev.WebServer40.EXE` in the task manager before anything static is called again.

q1) Is this normal, and if Yes, why?
q2) If no, then I would expect the ASP.NET Development Server to be restarted each time I restart a debugging session. **How can I turn this on?**

**UPDATE:**
Recompiling *sometimes* causes Application_Start to be called, not always.

I've resorted to calling a batch file in the prebuild, eg

kill_WebServer40.bat

which contains

```
taskkill /F /IM WebDev.WebServer40.EXE
exit 0
```

If you embed those two commands directly into the pre-build textarea your compilation will fail if the WebServer isnt running already. [This](http://brianseekford.com/index.php/tag/prebuild/) linked helped fix that.

Surprised this wasn't discussed more/previously -  when developing an app, as if you have any static data/caches and you want to run the application 'clean' you would run into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's normal. It will restart if you touch the web.config or recompile. The development server continues to run the application in the background after you stop debugging.

You can stop the development server in the task tray by right clicking on the icon and choosing stop.

There isn't a way to force a application restart every time you hit debug. This would only be needed for the edge case where you are debugging application start up. Just hit rebuild before debugging and it will have the desired affect.

Comment: neither touching the web.config or recompiling causes the web server to restart. (consistently)

Comment: Either of those should cause your application to restart, (not the server) and your Aplication_Start break point should get hit. By recompiling I mean rebuild, not build.